# Where to configure azure cosmos database resource token validity period?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#resource-tokens-) described Resource token has customizable validity period. The default valid time span is one hour. Token lifetime, however, may be explicitly specified, up to a maximum of five hours. But I could not find place to configure it. I want to modify token lifetime 10 minutes. Does anybody changed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest version of [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/), the `CreatePermissionAsync` method on the `User` object takes an `tokenExpiryInSeconds` argument. The method implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/c5a5b8836aa8ce2f8d93a863f4abdb2d2818fa5b/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/User/User.cs#L123).